# How do I use letter as a variable/placeholder in a math equation?

Tags: java, math, polynomial-math, quadratic

Sorry if that title confused you its kinda hard for me to ask this without explaining it.
I am writing a (fairly) simple program to find the roots of a quartic (biquadratic) function.
My main question (I should know this >.>) is how do i get x in the quartic function (ax^4 * bx^3 * cx^2 * dx * e = 0) to stay as x and not be given a value. just sorta a place holder. this is part of it: ( b1 * x * c1 / 2 ); so i dont want x to be replaced. i just want it to stay as x and everything else around it multiply as you normaly would when solving the problem by hand.

My second question is from this site:

http://easycalculation.com/algebra/learn-quartic-equation.php

We haven't covered Quartics in school yet but We have covered cubics and quadratics so I know enough that i can follow a long for the most part except for right after it talks about the discriminant.

y2=(- term1 + r13*cos(q3+(2∏)/3) )

y3=(- term1 + r13*cos(q3+(4∏)/3) )

i dont get the parts with 2∏ and 4∏. If you know a simple way to explain it, please do :D  if not i can always look it up and try to figure it out from there.

And my last question. I know how with the discriminant of quadratics depending on what it is depends on one root, no roots, or two roots. How does that apply with quartics and what should i do to check for that in my code (if you think i cant figure it out lol).

ummm i believe thats it. i can add info if needed. I dont think my code would be needed but i would prefer not to post it either way.

Thanks for the help.
-Ryan

Comment: Perhaps you'll want to use a programming language or system that was built specifically for this functionality -- to manipulate equations and solve them algebraically -- such as Mathematica, Maple or Matlab/Octave. e.g., [computer algebra systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems)

Comment: Most of this sounds like a pure-maths question, not a programming question...

Comment: Ask the [mathy questions here](http://math.stackexchange.com/). There are any number of equation-solving algorithms, I'd probably try searching for those first and coming back when you have a specific question regarding one of them.

Comment: No I'm strictly sticking with java on this one. i just mainly need to use something to act as a place holder but so that when x is multiplied by another x it becomes x^2

Comment: What do you mean as a placeholder? Are you trying to find the answer to an equation or are you trying to represent the equation as it is being "worked out"? Your variable for `x` represents `x`. If you times `x` by itself (`x *= x`) it's equivalent to `x^2`. Alternatively look at the [Math.Pow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29) function.

Comment: yes but wouldn't doing that assign it an ascii value?

Comment: ascii value? What the heck? No, it would not.

Comment: As @HovercraftFullOfEels said, no it would not. I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how programming works. What made you decide to use Java to start with? There are entire programming languages and systems built for what it seems you want.

Answer (score 1):

The [approach cited](http://easycalculation.com/algebra/learn-quartic-equation.php) relies on a trigonometric identity described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Trigonometric_.28and_hyperbolic.29_method) used to solve  cubic equations. The symbol `∏` is a capital `π`, or [`Math.PI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#PI) in Java.

See also this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8285147/230513) that uses `org.jscience.mathematics.function.Polynomial` and references a convenient root-finding algorithm.

Comment: Although not completely general, certain [`JScience`](http://jscience.org/api/index.html) constructs such as `Polynomial` admit limited symbolic manipulation (e.g. arithmetic, evaluation, differentiation, integration) using `Variable` and `Term`.

Answer (score 0):

The approach that you are looking for is called **Symbolic Programming**.

I do not, however, know of any stable Java libraries which allow for such programming.