# Java - derived generics class for math functions

Tags: java, generics

This was a hard problem to try and search for as I've seen no other specific issues like this, so I apologize if there turns out to be a duplicate thread I haven't found. This is a programming problem that is not related to homework in a class, that I am having issues implementing exactly according to spec.

If I want to create a

```
Function<T>
```

generic abstract class, whose only abstract method is

```
Apply<T>(T input1, input2)
```

and then extend into other derived function classes like an AddTwoNumbers class, to which Apply would return the sum of those input1 and input2 of type T (in practice this should be Integer or Double), how can I implement this?

I run into a problem when I first have

```
public abstract class Function<T1 extends Number> {
    public abstract T1 apply(T1 input1, T1 input2);
}
public class AddTwoNumbers<T1 extends Number> extends Function<T1> {
    public T1 apply(T1 input1, T1 input2) {
        return input1.intValue() + input2.intValue(); //Error, needs to return type T1, not int or even Integer()
    }
}
```

It is required that Function be generic that allows types, but inpractice it can be expected that AddTwoNumbers will be using Integers exclusively for the sake of this problem.  Is there a way I can write the apply() method in AddTwoNumbers, such that

1. AddTwoNumbers implements the abstract methods inherited from Function exactly
2. Somehow add the two T1 values and return a T1 value properly?

The fact that I can't safely cast a T1 to an Integer, and also retain the overriding of Apply is the troublesome part.

This is generalization of the issue I was looking into.

Comment: You may be looking for [`JScience`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jscience/info), for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8285147/230513).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class AddTwoIntegers extends Function< Integer > {
...
}
```

Comment: +1 I think this is the correct answer. But a static typed method would be a more interesting question

Comment: hey you were right!  Thank you so much Judge Mental!  I tried doing it AddTwoIntegers<Integer> and didn't work but the syntax you specified is correct.

Also, I also think Apply() should be a static method but java doesn't allow Abstract Static methods.  Some people think it makes sense but I wish they would allow both.

Comment: Why would `apply` make any sense as a static method? There's no functional object instance any more and no concept of overriding in that case.

Comment: I probably just don't understand the idea that this exercise is trying to get across -- a functional object instance.  I'm used to thinking of it in terms of, if the function isn't using any data members of the class then might as well make it static.

Comment: Check out the Flyweight design pattern. It would make sense to share a single, global (static?) instance of this class throughout your program, as you point out.  But in this model there has to be at least one instance to represent each different function that you want to use.

Comment: Also, as a matter of SO etiquette, one normally clicks the checkmark next to an answer if it is correct.

Comment: Thanks Judge Mental, as I said I'm new so I appreciate the tip.  Checked!

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for unfortunately isn't possible within the Java specification.  There is no abstraction layer which accounts for both primitive `ints` and primitive `doubles`, or in fact any combination of primitives, so you are forced to create two classes for this.

There are ways of doing this, however, which are much better than writing an `AddTwoIntegers.java` file AND an `AddTwoDoubles.java` file.

Option 1:  Create an `AdditionFunctions` class, and give it two static members:  `INTS` and `DOUBLES`.  You can do this using anonymous classes easily.

Option 2:  Use a template, if you can incorporate the generation step into your build process.  [Trove](https://bitbucket.org/robeden/trove) does this to great effect