# How do I create symbolic variables/functions involving vectors using JScience?

Tags: java, vector, jscience

How do I create symbolic variables/functions involving vectors using JScience? Creating float variables is easy:

```
Variable<Float64> varX = Variable.local<Float64>("x");
```

How can I do the same for a vector? Once I have a vector variable, how do I create
a `Polynomial` involving that vector (say, by using Euclidean distance)?

Answer (score 1):

Given a `Vector<Float64>` of coefficients, you can construct a `Polynomial<Float64>` as shown below. As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8285147/230513), the highest order coefficient is first for convenience in applying Horner's scheme.

```
public static Polynomial<Float64> create(Vector<Float64> v) {
    Variable<Float64> x = new Variable.Local<Float64>("x");
    Polynomial<Float64> px = Polynomial.valueOf(Float64.ZERO, x);
    for (int i = 0, e = v.getDimension() - 1; i < v.getDimension(); i++, e--) {
        px = px.plus(Polynomial.valueOf(v.get(i), Term.valueOf(x, e)));
    }
    return px;
}
```

Typical usage:

```
Polynomial<Float64> px = create(Float64Vector.valueOf(3, 2, 1));
System.out.println(px);
System.out.println(px.evaluate(Float64.ONE));
```

Console:

```
[3.0]x² + [2.0]x + [1.0]
6.0
```